# convert comment as answer

Tags: discussion, support

Hi I have gone through a Question in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250996/how-to-completely-remove-thunderbird) main site where we have the answer as in comment format. If we can convert the comment as answer then we can close the similar [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295126/weird-thunderbird-uninstall-problem) like this and future Questions also.

So what do you suggest me to do ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this order:

1. Ask the commenter to post their comment as an answer, making sure to mention their name (like @Jai) so they get a notification.
2. Wait for some time so they can act on this. 24-48 hours should be long enough but it doesn't really matter if it's longer than that.
3. Post the answer as a community wiki answer, mentioning the person who posted it. Posting as a CW means you won't get any of the reputation from votes for the post. Using that feature here shows it was not your idea and that you have good manners.

Comment: I did as you suggested.

Comment: But it could be usable when you set a bounty and somebody just by comment give a good answer. I would like to give a bounty to that person, but actually it is not possible (it is a comment). Some possibility to change comment to the answer with original author would be great.

Comment: I follow this outline myself, although I don't bother posting as a community wiki, especially since there's usually quite a bit of effort involved in converting a short comment to a full-fledged answer.

Comment: You may use another person's words, ideas, or information, but to do so without acknowledgment is plagiarism. - bowdoin.edu